# Disable toc items based on build parameter in DocFx

Tags: docfx

I am looking for a solution where I can change the generated output of a docfx build based on some parameters during build time. I have seen that there is a filter property in docfx.json where I can filter out some api stuff. But I would like to change the structure/content of my site which is generated from the toc.yml files.

The reason I would like to have this feature is that I generate the documentation specific for every customer we have. Based on the features a customer has registered on our product some pages of the static documentation have to appear and some pages should not be available for this customer.

Comment: Are you able to add any specifics?

Comment: @hcdocs - I have added my use case for this request to the question

Answer (score 0):

This may be something to start with:

**File structure**

```
articles
--topic1.md
--topic2.md
--topic3.md
--topic4.md
customer1
--index.md
--toc.yml
customer2
--index.md
--toc.yml
```

**customer1/toc.yml**

```
 - name: Customer 1 home
   homepage: index.md
 - name: Topic 1
   href: ../articles/topic1.md
 - name: Topic 2
   href: ../articles/topic2.md
```

**customer2/toc.yml**

```
 - name: Customer 2 home
   homepage: index.md
 - name: Topic 1
   href: ../articles/topic1.md
 - name: Topic 2
   href: ../articles/topic2.md
 - name: Topic 3
   href: ../articles/topic1.md
 - name: Topic 4
   href: ../articles/topic2.md
```

**docfx.json**

```
{
  "build": {
    "content": [
      {
        "files": [
          "articles/*.md",
          "customer1/**",
          "customer2/**"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "dest": "_site"
  }
}
```

**Output site structure**

```
articles
--topic1.html
--topic2.html
--topic3.html
--topic4.html
customer1
--index.html
--toc.html
customer2
--index.html
--toc.html
```

**Result**

`site/customer1` is a customized landing page and table of contents for Customer 1

`site/customer2` is a customized landing page and table of contents for Customer 2